# Why does checking the Console.OutputEncoding take so long?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

I'm running some performance profiling on my application, and found that checking the console output encoding takes nearly twice as long to check as my application does to run a full performance iteration.

I'm checking via:

```
Console.OutputEncoding.EncodingName != Encoding.UTF8.EncodingName
```

This check takes ~80 ticks (8,000 ns), my entire application (generating console tables) only takes ~50 ticks (5,000 ns) to run without this, and goes through hundreds of conditions.

Why does checking the output encoding take so much time? Can I speed this up?

Comment: I wonder if you can convert this false equal to a linq expression. Can you add some more context of what your expression is checking?

Comment: @BenderBending It's just checking the encoding. If the console encoding does not equal UTF8, then I set it to UTF8. LINQ would probably be slower since I would be adding a level of indirection.

Comment: Can the user that voted to close for being too broad explain why you think this is too broad? The scope seems pretty clear-cut to me.

Comment: Seems clear to me as well, this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to hazard a guess it's because you're comparing the `EncodingName`, which results in a potentially expensive lookup (and subsequent string comparison).  Is there a reason you don't just compare the encodings directly?

```
!Console.OutputEncoding.Equals( Encoding.UTF8 )
```

Testing it locally that seems much faster.

Comment: That takes about the same amount of time, interesting though with this way it jumps from 65-100 ticks per check. The `EncodingName` check consistently hangs around 80 +=2 ticks.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell I cannot reproduce that locally.  For me comparing directly is significantly faster than comparing the `EncodingName` property.  How are you profiling this?

Comment: Good call, my test for this was flawed, I accidently left the `.EncodingName` bit on `Encoding.UTF8`. I am using the stopwatch to record elapsed ticks. In release build this takes 3 ticks, vs the name check which takes 38 ticks.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Ah hah!  Glad to hear I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Reference source for the getter of `OutputEncoding`: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,594

```
public static Encoding OutputEncoding {
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    get {

        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Encoding>() != null);

        if (null != _outputEncoding)
            return _outputEncoding;

        lock(InternalSyncObject) {

            if (null != _outputEncoding)
                return _outputEncoding;

            uint cp = Win32Native.GetConsoleOutputCP();
            _outputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding((int) cp);
            return _outputEncoding;
        }
    }
    ...
```

The first thing I notice is that it's taking a lock, so there's a bit of overhead there already. It also seems to be lazily instantiated: the first time you get `OutputEncoding`, it needs to do a PInvoke followed by [`Encoding.GetEncoding`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs,416) (which, if you can see, is not a trivial task). But all subsequent calls avoid the lock and return the already-instantiated value. So if you're getting it multiple times, the cost will be amortized to nearly nothing anyway.

If you're only getting it once... do you *really* need to optimize something that only takes 8 microseconds?

Comment: I get it multiple times, I only measure after the first time in case it did lazy-load. As for optimization, my library is built with heavy optimization in mind. Normally I would say that 8 microsecond doesn't matter, but when that's twice as long as my library takes to instantiate, collect data, format, and output I want to optimize it.

Comment: After looking it over, it doesn't look like there is any way around it unless I simulated the `uint cp = Win32Native.GetConsoleOutputCP();` call, but I imagine that can change between framework versions since it's internal.